# Loop through folder get data from specific ranges copy to master

Tags: excel, vba, loops, copy, paste

Im working on creating an macro that will pull data from a specific group of ranges across many files in one folder and feed that data into a master file in the same folder. When running the macro, it appears to be functioning but does not paste data in the master file. No errors were given when running the code. Wondering if I'm missing something or need to break this up as copy / paste?

```
    Sub CopyDataLoop()
    
       Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
       Dim wbSource As Workbook
       Dim wsSource As Worksheet
       Dim rowTarget As Long
       Dim myFolder As String, sFile As String
       
       
            myFolder = "C:\TempDriveTest\"
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            
            rowTarget = 3
            
            
            
           Application.ScreenUpdating = False
           
         
           Set wsTarget = Sheets("Sheet1")
           
        
           sFile = Dir(myFolder & "*.xls*" & "*.xlsm*" & vbNormal)
           Do Until sFile = ""
              
         
              Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(myFolder & sFile)
              Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets("Table of Contents")
              
        
              With wsTarget
                 .Range("A" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("B147").Value
                 .Range("B" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("B149").Value
                 .Range("C" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("D3").Value
                 .Range("D" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("D4").Value
                 .Range("E" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("D5").Value
                 .Range("F" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("D7").Value
                 .Range("G" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("D16").Value
                 .Range("H" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("J3").Value
                 .Range("I" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("J18").Value
                 .Range("J" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("D39").Value
                 .Range("K" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("D54").Value
                 .Range("L" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("J39").Value
                 .Range("M" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("J54").Value
                 .Range("N" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("D76").Value
                 .Range("O" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("J76").Value
                 .Range("P" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("D92").Value
                 .Range("Q" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("J92").Value
                 .Range("R" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("D113").Value
                 .Range("S" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("J112").Value
                 .Range("T" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("D128").Value
                 .Range("U" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("J128").Value
                 
              End With
              
              
              wbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
              rowTarget = rowTarget + 1
              sFile = Dir()
           Loop
           
    End Sub
    Sub TurnOnEvents()
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: Don't forget to set `Application.ScreenUpdating=True` otherwise you won't see any updates in your target file, since you switched it off (twice) early in the macro...

Comment: Use `sFile = Dir(myFolder & "*.xls*", vbNormal)`.

Comment: Maybe try `Set wsTarget = activeworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")` ?  ---or---- `Set wsTarget = thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")`